# How to perform the and operation in redis like mysql?

Tags: redis

Select * from student where id=1 and college='sss' so how it will achieved in redis databas.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a query you could perform on an [SQL database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

[Redis](http://redis.io/) however is a [key-value store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_stores). Therefore it does not work with SQL queries.

I suggest trying the [interactive tutorial](http://try.redis.io/) to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to maintain your own index, for example in a [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset), or use a package like [stdnet](http://lsbardel.github.io/python-stdnet/), which does the indexing for you.